# Is Reactive Extensions open-source?

Tags: .net, system.reactive

Is Reactive Extensions open-source? Will Microsoft open-source it?

I'm looking to read the source code to better understand how it's implemented. I'd like to see the unit tests, so I can run them against some of my own code reimplementing some of `Reactive.Linq`.

I know Microsoft open-sourced F# which is handy for developers https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In case you've missed it, Rx is now open-source: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/interoperability/archive/2012/11/06/ms-open-tech-open-sources-rx-reactive-extensions-a-cure-for-asynchronous-data-streams-in-cloud-programming.aspx

1. http://rx.codeplex.com/
2. https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET

Answer (score 5):

**Update 07/11/2012:** Forgot about this, it's now Open Source, yay!

https://rx.codeplex.com/

https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET

This also include Interactive Extensions.

---

A quick search doesn't throw up any CodePlex links, so I'm going to say it isn't open source.

Bart De Smet has done loads of videos about Rx and how it works and how to use it:

http://channel9.msdn.com/Tags/reactive+extensions

To see the internals, if you know the assembly it is stored in, the only remaining option is to disassemble it using something like [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx) or [dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/).

Will Microsoft open source it? They released the .NET source a while back, perhaps they will do the same. This isn't the same as open source, but you can at least step into the code and see what it's all about. I haven't gone looking, but the Rx stuff might already be in there.

Answer (score 3):

Only the JavaScript implementation of Rx is open sourced. https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions